# Inline Parameterized Query Timing out

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I have this inline parameterized query which started timing out recently.

```
Dim dal As New DalMain()

Dim sbSql As New StringBuilder()
sbSql.Append(" select column1, column2 ")
sbSql.Append(" from table ")
sbSql.Append(" where column3 = @Value ")

dal.AddSqlParms("@Value", DalMain.SqlParmType.STR, "100")
```

where DalMain is data access class and DalMain.SqlParmType.STR is type DbType.String. The query was running fine for last 5 years now I am getting time out when I run it.

The same query runs fine in sql management studio. If I hard code the value as below then it runs fine without a timeout.

```
sbSql.Append(" select column1, column2 ")
sbSql.Append(" from table ")
sbSql.Append(" where column3 = '100' ")
```

The problem is happening only with that particular table, rest of the parameterized queries are working fine. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like Parameter Sniffing - try creating a stored procedure instead of using dynamic sql.

Comment: Do a restart of the sql server will fix this problem? Is there any other solution other than writing a new stored procedure.

Comment: Why would you want to use dynamic sql instead of a stored procedure?  SPs are usually more efficient, prevent SQL injection, and are more easy to maintain.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg parametarized query prevents sql injection. And also SP = more maintenance.

Comment: I have a feeling that there is something else in your real query that you don't show here. And also, we don't know what happens in your `DalMain`. Put sql server profiler on it - see what executing sql looks like and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the data type nchar/nvarchar on the database? SQL server often doesn't use the index if the datatype on the db is varchar and the parameter supplied is declared as nvarchar (and visa versa). Check what is generated in sql profiler to make sure.

Comment: You are right. My column is varchar and I was using dbtype as string which was converted to nvarchar. Hence it was not using the index to run the query. But the interesting thing is it was running fine for the last 3-4 years and table has around 30 million records. I tried dbtype as Ansistring and it is running fine now.